# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I try add data to database using ajax. I prepare data:

```
$(".panel").on('click','.buttons_save',function() {
    groupIdD = this.id;
    groupNameD=$("#groupName").val();
    groupDescriptionD=$("#groupDescription").val();
    paramGroupD=$("#paramGroup").val();
    paramOrderD=$("#paramOrder").val();

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxSetGroupParams,
        data: { 
            groupId: groupIdD,
            paramGroup: groupNameD,
            groupName: groupDescriptionD,
            groupDescription: paramGroupD,
            paramOrder: paramOrderD
        }
    })

    .done(function() {
        alert( "success" );
    })
    .fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    })


});
```

And I add this data to database (everything is ok, data are add to database).
$polaczenie_z_baza=$_SESSION['db']['connectObjs']['system'];

```
$id_group=$_REQUEST['groupId'];
$paramGroup=$_REQUEST['paramGroup'];
$groupName=$_REQUEST['groupName'];
$groupDescription=$_REQUEST['groupDescription'];
if (isset($_REQUEST['paramOrder'])) {
    $paramOrder=$_REQUEST['paramOrder'];
}
else {
    $paramOrder=0;
}

$qUpdateData    = '
UPDATE
`grupy_parametrow_konfiguracyjnych`
SET
`id_grupa_nadrzedna` ='.$paramGroup.',
`nazwa_grupy` = '.$groupName.',
`opis_grupy` = '.$groupDescription.',
`kolejnosc` ='.$paramOrder.'
WHERE
`id_grupa_parametrow` = '.$id_group; 

$result = stdIUDQuery( $qUpdateData, $polaczenie_z_baza);
```

But always I have fail information:

```
parsererror
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data

return window.JSON.parse( data );
```

Comment: Show your json data structure

Comment: I hope this is only a minimal example, if not you should take care for SQL Injection techniques.

Comment: This is modified example. I have data validation and prepared statments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be happening because your server isn't returning JSON, but you're telling jQuery that it is. Since you're not using the contents of the response from the server in your done handler, you can simply remove the `dataType: "json",` from your `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

3 ideas also to debug the error.

**A firefox**

1. save the response in notepad as idea.json
2. open in firefox
3. it will show you if is good json or not.

**B console.log(variable.constructor)**

check if is string or json with console.log(variable_name.constructor);

**C check the correct line**

check all JSON.parse lines, my problem was for 20 mins checking the wrong line.